# Get 1st number between every 10 numbers

Tags: c#

I have 120 groups, each group has 10 numbers.

Suppose if 24 is in the loop I want to get in which group it is? Means if 24 is there then I want to get 21 because 24 comes between 21-30.

Give me logic using if or for loop whatever.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        Response.Write(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Are *all* the groups 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc? It would really help if you'd give a short but complete example program.

Comment: @JonSkeet whatever you explained is correct. Yes all the groups are 1-10,11-20,21-30 like this.

Comment: Have you tried to make it?

Comment: I tried this one: for(int i=0; i<120;i++){if(i%10==0){reponse.write(i.tostring();)}}.   But it is not helping

Comment: @DipaliWagh:- Please edit your question and update your code over there. Dont paste code in comments

Comment: And is your input guaranteed to be in one of the groups? If so, it's just `(((input - 1) / 10) * 10) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
static int starter(int n)
{
    var x = n % 10;
    return n - x + 1;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(starter(24));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how in pack the numbers in groups, so I'm giving you a solution and you have to change it for your own needs.

Suppose the number are packed in an ArrayList and the groups are then packed together in another ArrayList. This way you would have an ArrayList of several ArrayList with number. So my solution would be:

```
private int FindNumber(int number)
{
    int count = 0;
    int gindex = -1;
    foreach(group g in groups)
    {
        if(g.contains(number))      
        gindex = count;
        count++;           
    }
    ArrayList aux = groups[gindex];
    return aux[0];
 }
```

Edit after reading Jester response. I guess you would like the first number of the 10 groups so

```
private int FindNumber(int number)
{
    int ret
    foreach(group g in groups)
    {
        if(g.contains(number))      
        {
            var x = number % 10;
            ret = number - x + 1;
        }
    }

    return ret;
 }
```

Jester response is right in the main idea but that doesn't work if you don't have the number in the group.